# How to build my relationships in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm building a barcodes database which retrieve data from mobile provider companies based on country names.

Each provider has it's own code for specific country. Some providers may have the same code for a country.

I have 3 tables in my database named `countries`, `providers` and `country_codes`.

I have also 3 Models for these tables called `Country`, `Provider` and `CountryCode`.

I want to create relationships between those with Laravel eloquent using Models.

Table Structures Diagram 1:
[Table Structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR5By.jpg)

Table Structures Diagram 2:
[Table Structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRG85.jpg)

I want to create an construct function in my CountryCode Model that when I call this model name in my controller with 2 arguments, it give me the code placed in country_codes table row.

For example when I call: `new CountryCode('Spain', 'Apple')` , It should return `64`.

How can I build this with Models and Relationships?

I use Laravel 6.x

Comment: Have you tried using pivot tables? Try this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Answer (score 1):

Add to Provider model

```
 public function countries()
   {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country');
   }
```

Add to Country model

```
public function providers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Provider');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed method signature won't match the constructor of the base Eloquent Model class:

```php
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
   //...
}
```

*Query scopes* allow for a similar desired syntax:

```php
CountryCode::fromCountryProvider('Spain', 'Apple');
```

An example implementation that should give you an idea on how to achieve this:

```php
public function scopeFromCountryProvider($query, $country, $provider)
{
    $query->whereHas('countries', function($subquery_country) use ($country) {

        $subquery_country->where('name', $country);

    })->whereHas('providers', function($subquery_provider) use ($provider) {

        $subquery_provider->where('name', $provider);

    });
}

public function countries()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class);
}

public function providers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Provider::class)
}
```